# Android: How to determine waiting threads?

Tags: android, unit-testing

Want to create a unit test for android library project. I need to test if the given thread is waiting (synchronized object.wait() was called) or not. Is it possible to determine it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common way to write unit tests to see if a method is called is to create a mock object that overrides the method to check and sets a flag when it is called.  For example:

```
public class MockYourClass extends YourClass {
    public boolean mWaitWasCalled = false;
    @Override
    public void wait() {
        mWaitWasCalled = true;
        super.wait();
   }
}
```

Substitute the use of your class for this mock and then check that `assertTrue(mockClass.mWaitWasCalled)`

Given a random object, there's no way to tell if a thread is waiting on it.